# Pig Latin Decoder has errors

Tags: python

I need help on why this code won't work. The error is on line 13. There may be more errors in the code and if you find some just tell me how to fix them. Thank you!

```
decode_PLoSM = raw_input("Enter pig latin for a Pig Latin decoder or enter "
      "secret message for a secret message decoder")

if decode_PLoSM == "secret message":
    check = raw_input("Is there an other?")
    if check == "no":
        where = raw_input("Enter the where")
        new_where = where[:-2]
        new_where_2 = new_where[-1] + new_where[:-1]
        when = raw_input("Enter the when")
        new_when = when[:-2]
        new_when_2 = new_when[-1] + new_when[:-1]
        print "Meet me in " + str(new_where_2) " at " + str(new_when_2)
    elif check == "yes":
        other_word = raw_input("Enter other")
        where_2 = raw_input("Enter the where")
        new_where_2 = where_2[:-2]
        new_where_2_2 = new_where_2[-1] + new_where_2[:-1]
        when_2 = raw_input("Enter the when")
        new_when_2 = when_2[:-2]
        new_when_2_2 = new_when_2[-1] + new_when_2[:-1]
        other_word = raw_input("Enter the when")
        other_word_2 = other_word_2[:-2]
        other_word_2_2 = other_word_2[-1] + other_word_2[:-1]
        print "Meet me in " new_where_2 + " at " + new_when_2
    else:
        print ""
elif decode_PLoSM == "pig latin":
    pig_latin_word = raw_input("Enter the Pig Latin word")
    new_PLW = pig_latin_word[:-2]
    new_PLW_2 = new_PLW[-1] + new_PLW[:-1]
    print new_PLW_2.lower()
else:
    print "Please enter a word containing no numbers or symbols"
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message and any traceback that accompanies it, so people aren't forced to run your code to try and help you.

Comment: What is the full error? What is line 13 here?

Answer (score 0):

Add + to concatenate the strings :

```
print "Meet me in  + new_where_2 +  at  + new_where_2"
```